# Multiple woocommerce store in one wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, multistore

I am building a site for a client, who displays a catalog of heavy-duty machines (the user cannot directly order a machine, but he can request informations via a contact form). The site has been built in wordpress and woocommerce, for ease of use and capability of importing .xml and .csv files.

My client is now widening his market, by also selling spare parts for his heavy-duty machines. The site should be able to display both the machines and the spare parts, in two different sections of the same site, allowing the direct order for the spare parts but not for the heavy-duty machines.

It would also be better if, in the backend of the store, spare parts and heavy-duty machines would be separate, in order to manage them more easily by the two separate offices.

Is there any plugin that can "split" in two parts woocommerce products' catalog? Or is any more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: @MattHamer5 I'd like to keep this as a backup solutions. Different products would be managed by different offices and (probably) with different ways of synchronizing databases.

Comment: The only way I can think of doing this would just be to create a multisite - install the plugin on both and have one selling the spare parts and the other as just a catalog of the machinery, there's no way to setup two different stores on the same site using WooCommerce.

Comment: Create a category for parts and category for machines. Add a function to remove purchasing for products marked with category machines, and leave it for parts.